# How do I give prediction input in Vowpal Wabbit format? I have to give tags as well and they are numbers, like this-

Tags: vowpalwabbit

```
'1234| feature1:12 feature2:2.3 feature3:34.12 feature4=1
'9045| feature1:32 feature2:8.0 feature3:90.9 feature4=0
```

The tags here are numbers and features are both quantitative and categorical.
I have tried this format but it gives EOL error. The same format with label is working for input file (Training set).

Comment: Could you please provide full reproducible example?  I tried but can't reproduce (on Ubuntu 16.04 with latest code) without a trainset, command line and exact error you're getting.  I actually get good predictions by loading a pre-trained model `-i modelfile`, asking `vw` to predict (`-p predictfile`) and copying the 2 lines in the question as the input.  A wild guess: do you happen to have lines ending with anything other than newlines ("\n") ?

Comment: I tried to simulate some examples like this and run VW, it is running fine. Let me see what is the problem with actual data, if it persists, I will revert back.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, it is working. The data had some other problem but I have resolved it. Thanks!